# Storing data that updates yearly in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a collection called `Company` and it has details of a company as its fields like name, address, etc. But then I also have financial data that updates annually for that company. I am, however, not sure how to structure this. I have produced two options but I am not sure which is best. Ideally, the first option is the one I go with, but I worry that if I want to pull through companies with financial data only for the year 2017, for example, I will struggle.

Any recommendations?

First: More dynamic and doesn't require Mongoose schema amendments every year:

```
{
  companyName: {
    type: String
  },
  financials: [
    {
      year: {
        type: Number
      },
      revenue: {
        type: Number
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Second: Easier to query:

```
{
  companyName: {
    type: String
  },
  financials: {
    year2017: {
      revenue: {
        type: Number
      }
    },
    year2018: {
      revenue: {
        type: Number
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One of the most important rule (imo) to design mongodb data : Avoid storing data in key!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in my comment, avoid storing data in keys. So your first scheme is the good one. Consider this dataset :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8e7ba1325bec7b317b949f"), 
    "companyName" : "ABC", 
    "financials" : [
        {
            "year" : 2015.0, 
            "revenue" : 15.0
        }, 
        {
            "year" : 2016.0, 
            "revenue" : 18.0
        }, 
        {
            "year" : 2017.0, 
            "revenue" : 25.0
        }, 
        {
            "year" : 2018.0, 
            "revenue" : 19.0
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8e84234193bb17fff8d5e5"), 
    "companyName" : "BCD", 
    "financials" : [
        {
            "year" : 2016.0, 
            "revenue" : 38.0
        }, 
        {
            "year" : 2017.0, 
            "revenue" : 18.0
        }, 
        {
            "year" : 2018.0, 
            "revenue" : 5.0
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8e84394193bb17fff8d5e6"), 
    "companyName" : "CDE", 
    "financials" : [
        {
            "year" : 2017.0, 
            "revenue" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "year" : 2018.0, 
            "revenue" : 75.0
        }
    ]
}
```

---

---

To retrieve companies that had revenues in 2015, use [$elemMatch **query** operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) :

```
db['01'].find({financials:{$elemMatch:{year:2015}}})
```

Result :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8e7ba1325bec7b317b949f"), 
    "companyName" : "ABC", 
    "financials" : [
        {
            "year" : 2015.0, 
            "revenue" : 15.0
        }, 
        {
            "year" : 2016.0, 
            "revenue" : 18.0
        }, 
        {
            "year" : 2017.0, 
            "revenue" : 25.0
        }, 
        {
            "year" : 2018.0, 
            "revenue" : 19.0
        }
    ]
}
```

---

---

To retrieve only year 2017 for each companies, use the [$elemMatch **projection**
operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) :

```
db['01'].find(
{}, // <= Query
{companyName:1,financials:{$elemMatch:{year:2017}}}    // <= Projection
)
```

Result :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8e7ba1325bec7b317b949f"), 
    "companyName" : "ABC", 
    "financials" : [
        {
            "year" : 2017.0, 
            "revenue" : 25.0
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8e84234193bb17fff8d5e5"), 
    "companyName" : "BCD", 
    "financials" : [
        {
            "year" : 2017.0, 
            "revenue" : 18.0
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8e84394193bb17fff8d5e6"), 
    "companyName" : "CDE", 
    "financials" : [
        {
            "year" : 2017.0, 
            "revenue" : 3.0
        }
    ]
}
```

You can combine both to avoid getting documents that doesn't match the projection criterias.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can go with this as well, will be easier to query for a particular financial year:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8e7ba1325bec7b317b949f"),
    "companyName" : "ABC",
    "financials" : [ 
        {
            "2017" : {
                "revenue" : 20
            },
            "2018" : {
                "revenue" : 30
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is this valid syntax? I don't understand how you reference the array elements in `financials`. `company.financials[0]` or `company.financials["2017"]` but it can't be the latter because that suggests that "2017" is a key and not an index?

Comment: Yes of course it would be valid as we are not talking about JSONs specifically but about the schema structure

Comment: Ok thanks so how do I query this model to return the financial data for the year 2017 for example?

Comment: You have to perform aggregation on it to get only the financial data belonging to 2017 and not for other keys

Comment: Hey, I have just made an edit in my post, what I was trying to reference is this. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Now if you want to query for financial data for 2017.

Comment: You can use:
db.getCollection("").find({"financials.2017": {"$exists": true}})

Answer (score 0):

The first version (dynamic) has the big advantage of using fixed keys only, which I'd definitely prefer.

The query to filter for specific years only needs to use the `$elemMatch` operator, as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch%20here)

For your concrete case this should be along the lines of:

```
db.coll.find(
   { "companyName": "stackoverflow inc."},
   { 
      "companyName": 1,
      "financials" : { $elemMatch: { "year": 2018 } }
   }
)
```